# solr how to sort search results by count matches

Tags: solr, lucene

I have 4 records index by **Solr**:

```
1 hello planet dear friends 
2 hello world dear friends 
3 nothing 
4 just friends
```

I'm searching with this query:

```
select?q=world+dear+friends&wt=json&indent=true
```

The result is:

```
1 hello planet dear friends
2 hello world dear friends
4 just friends
```

But as you can see first record has 2 matches, second - 3 and fourth - 1 and i need the sequence of the result was:

```
2 hello world dear friends //3 matches
1 hello planet dear friends //2 matches
4 just friends//1 match
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What does the debugQuery say? If you're actually matching against what you say you're matching against, the result should be the one you want by default. The problem is _probably_ that you're talking about a situation where one of the terms is more important (as it occurs in very few documents), or where the termFreq or position in relation to other tokens makes it score higher. debugQuery will show you exactly why this happens.

Comment: potentially you could do some Boolean OR query to get needed behaviour

Comment: i'm new to Solr so what is debugQuery? if you mean debugQuery=true in the address bar so then it gives me nothing new in the result.